# Как установить "this" в методе объекта?

Tags: javascript, массивы, this

```
 getIncome: function () {
    const itThis = this;
    incomeItems.forEach(function (item) {
      const itemIncome = item.querySelector(".income-title").value;
      const cashIncome = item.querySelector(".income-amount").value;

      itThis.income[itemIncome] = cashIncome;
    });
  },
```

Такое сохранение this уже устарело и не совсем корректно. Кажется у  forEach есть параметр для контекста, подскажите какой.

Comment: Внутри forEach можно заменить обычную функцию на стрелочную. У него нет собственного this - получит его от внешней функции.

Comment: @Qwertiy https://jsfiddle.net/Ltauqz0n/ - работает ведь...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, тьфу.. Я перепутал функцию в forEach с самой функцией-методом - вот там бы не работало.

Comment: тут вообще forEach не нужен. Нужно использовать либо for, либо reduce, тогда и проблем с this не будет

Answer (score 2):

Второй. У него их всего 2: первый - функция, а второй - this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Как можно сделать по другому? Не используя подмену this

Comment: @Dias, например, как OPTIMUS PRIME написал в комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

```
getIncome: function () {
    incomeItems.forEach(function (item) {
      const itemIncome = item.querySelector(".income-title").value;
      const cashIncome = item.querySelector(".income-amount").value;

      this.income[itemIncome] = cashIncome;
    } this);
  },
```

Нашел такое решение в старом синтаксисе.